# 苗- What does this do at the end of a sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

So I'm reading a novel and I have seen the author write 苗 multiple times, putting it at the end of a sentence. I am confused to as what the author is doing by writing 苗 at the end of a sentence, at first I thought it was a typo but the author has done it multiple times. So I searched up what 苗 was, and it meant seedling in Chinese but that still doesn't clear my confusion as to why its at the end of a sentence. I'm wondering if 苗 does have a meaning at the end of a sentence or if the author is mistakenly putting it there.

An example: “继续轰炸，务必将这些海怪军团通通炸死苗。”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would only make sense to me as a native speaker if this is a typo and it is supposed to be 喵， the Onomatopoeia for a cat's meow.

If this is the case, it's either that the character who said it has some connection to cats or possess cat-like quality. (Like being anthropomorphic) In this usage, it's like how in English you can write a cat saying 'I'm purrfect'.

It could also just be a way to appear cute. Like how in English you can write UwU.

The same usage can be observed in various Japanese popular media.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, yeah I think this is a typo by the author.